# How to create readable file stream from multiple files

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fs

Related to question: [Add specific image files to ffmpeg video with fluent-ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800614/add-specific-image-files-to-ffmpeg-video-with-fluent-ffmpeg)

Have array of file names that reside on network shares.  Would like to turn them into a timelapse video with a process on a nodejs server. I plan to use ffmpeg to do this.   FFMPEG doesn't allow file lists as input (as far as I can tell).  They do, however, allow a 'readable file stream'.

Is there a mechanism to create a readable file stream from an array of filenames?

The command they use in the fluent-ffmpeg example is: `var command = ffmpeg(fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file.avi'));`

... but obviously, this is only a single file.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was an interesting problem to look into so I created a `multiSourceStream` class that accepts an array of files and it will stream them one after another.  I've tested this on simple text files, including some very large files and it appears to do flow control properly, but more detailed testing is probably needed.

```
const {Readable} = require('stream');
const fs = require('fs');

class multiSourceStream extends Readable {
    constructor(files, options) {
        super(options);
        this.files = files.slice();
        this.readyToPush = false;
        this.nextFile();
    }
    nextFile() {
        if (this.files && this.files.length) {
            const rs = this.rs = fs.createReadStream(this.files.shift());
            // don't start flowing data until _read() is called
            if (!this.readyToPush) {
                rs.pause();
            }
            rs.on('data', chunk => {
                if (!this.push(chunk)) {
                    rs.pause();
                    this.readyToPush = false;
                }
            }).on('end', () => {
                this.nextFile();
            }).on('error', err => {
                this.destroy(err);
            });
        } else {
            this.rs = null;
            // all done
            this.push(null);
        }

    }
    _read() {
        this.readyToPush = true;
        if (this.rs) {
            this.rs.resume();
        } else {
            // all done
            this.push(null);
        }
    }
}


// example use
const ms = new multiSourceStream(['temp.txt', 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt']);
ms.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myoutput.txt'));
```

Comment: When using this, per your second-to-last-line, I use `const imageStream = new multiSourceStream(fileList);`    This gives me `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:568:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:353:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:382:19)...`

Comment: @lowcrawler - What version of node.js are you running?  I don't understand why there would be any synchronous  file I/O involved so something seems fishy and makes me think that error doesn't come from this code, but from something else.  FYI, this code works for me in node v14.4.0.  What is `fileList` in your code?  Please provide enough info I could maybe reproduce your problem.  What are you doing with the stream after you create it?  Can you provide the entire call stack for the rejection?

Comment: @lowcrawler - Also, can you run this exact code all by itself (as a test) where you pass the filenames of three text files that exist in the same directory?

Comment: I believe my error is coming from the fluent-ffmpeg require.  When I can get that to no error out `Unknown: unknown error, read` I'll re-try your code.  You are right, nothing exists in your code that would cause this.

Comment: will test before end of day.